# Tympanal versus antennal hearing: Why is tympanal hearing preferred for long-range?

Tags: particle-velocity, pressure, evolution

There are 2 types of ears (in insects see [here](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-ento-010715-023631)):

- **tympanal ears** to detect the sound pressure (force exerted by air particles on a surface)
- **hairs/antennal ears** to detect the air particle-velocity component of sound through air particle friction to free-standing hairs

A spherical sound source creates 2 components (see this [animation](https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/demos/burns_phd_animations/burns_phd_anim.html)):

- a **reactive** one which is present locally only (~ 1 wave length far from the source); it does not create any pressure field and the particle-velocity **attenuates with the inverse of distance square** (ref: table 4 of [Bennet-Clark 1998](https://doi.org/10.1098/rstb.1998.0219))
- an **active** one which propagates; both particle-velocity and pressure **attenuates with the inverse of distance** (ref: table 4 of [Bennet-Clark 1998](https://doi.org/10.1098/rstb.1998.0219))

I can understand why all species that use short-range communication have antennal ears because it more efficient to detect particle-velocity when they are in the near-field where the particle-velocity level increases far more then pressure level when getting close to the sound source (1/r^2 vs 1/r; see [table 4](https://doi.org/10.1098/rstb.1998.0219))

However, in terrestrial vertebrates and insects (e.g. criquets) that use long-range communication, they all have tympanal ears. I don't understand because both particle-velocity and pressure attenuates with 1/r, **so why would it be more efficient to have tympanal ears to hear at long-range**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is most likely to be found in the evolutionary history of the animals.

Tympanal ears have evolved a large number of times in insects (see for example [Göpfert and Hennig, 2012)](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-ento-010715-023631). The accepted theory for how this has happened is that in earless insects, the cuticle is set into vibration by loud sound and since they also have a very large number of mechanoreceptors attached to the cuticle (to inform about how the different body parts are placed relative to each other and inform about external pressure to the cuticle), even insects without a tympanum will be receptive to the pressure field of loud sound. This is enough for evolution to work on and through natural selection, the insects than benefit from hearing (such as nocturnal insects subject to bat predation) will quickly evolve thinner and thinner cuticle in useful places on the body, where a suitable mechanoreceptor is already in place ([Fullard and Yack (1993)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0169-5347(93)90200-9). There is nothing preventing this could also happen for the particle motion field, where sensory hairs with some other function than hearing also are sensitive to sound and then through natural selection their sensitivity to sound increased. In fact thee are examples of this, such as the sound sensitive hairs on the antennal palps of hawkmoths [Göpfert et al (2002)](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspb.2001.1646).

The vertebrate ear evolved in water and is fundamentally sensitive to particle motion, more specifically particle acceleration. However, the sensitivity of such an ear can easily be increased and the frequency range expanded, if there is an air bubble nearby. See the elegant experiment by [Chapman and Sand (1974)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0300-9629(74)90082-6), who show that the hearing in flatfish without swim bladders can be improved simply by attaching a small air-filled balloon to the head of the fish. Thus, when lungs and swim bladders evolved for other reasons in fish, their hearing imploved and turned into a pressure-sensitive ear, leading into the tympanal ear in tetrapods.

Chapman, C. J. and Sand, O. 1974. Field studies of hearing in two species of flatfish Pleuronectes platessa (L.) and Limanda limanda (L.) (Family Pleuronectidae). Comparative Biochemistry and Physiology 47A:371-385.

Fullard, J. H. and Yack, J. E. 1993. The evolutionarey biology of insect hearing. TREE 8:248-252.

Gopfert, M. C. and Hennig, R. M. 2016. Hearing in Insects. Annu Rev Entomol 61:257-276.

Göpfert, M. C., Surlykke, A. and Wasserthal, L. T. 2002. Tympanal and atympanal 'mouth-ears' in hawkmoths (Sphingidae). Proceedings of the Royal Society of London Series B-Biological Sciences 269:89-95.